# how to fix wordpress logo multiple h1 tags

Tags: wordpress, image, header

I have problem in my wordpress logo, when check in bing webmaster diagnostic tool, tell me i have multiple h1 tags, anyone know how to fix?

my site is https://xn--hxanfhlafbfwvgsh0akf7l.com and my wordpresss theme is colormag free version,

code is

```
<h1 class="logo">
        <a href="https://xn--hxanfhlafbfwvgsh0akf7l.com/" title="Ηλεκτρονικό τσιγάρο νέα, κριτικές, συμβουλές στο άτμισμα" rel="home">
            <img src="https://xn--hxanfhlafbfwvgsh0akf7l.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ηλεκτρονικό-τσιγάρο-νέα-κριτικές-συμβουλές-στο-άτμισμα-.png" alt="Ηλεκτρονικό τσιγάρο νέα, κριτικές, συμβουλές στο άτμισμα">
        </a>
    </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is in your template twice

```
<div
id="header-text" class="screen-reader-text"><h1 id="site-title">
<a
href="https://xn--hxanfhlafbfwvgsh0akf7l.com/" title="" rel="home"></a></h1></div></div><div
id="header-right-section"><div
id="header-right-sidebar" class="clearfix">
<aside
id="text-2" class="widget widget_text clearfix"><div
class="textwidget"><h1 class="H1">
<img
src="http://www.xn--hxanfhlafbfwvgsh0akf7l.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ηλεκτρονικό-τσιγάρο-νέα-κριτικές-συμβουλές-στο-άτμισμα-.png" alt="Ηλεκτρονικό τσιγάρο νέα, κριτικές, συμβουλές στο άτμισμα"></h1></div>
```

So what you need to do, is locate where in your template it is putting it in twice, create a child theme, and remove one of those from the template

So you could do a search inside the them, for either site-title or class="H1" and you should then be able to find the template. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually looking at it again now.

Comment: You have in header.php the h1 for site title, but the other one, is inside a text widget. Check your widgets, fo the one that holds this image http://www.xn--hxanfhlafbfwvgsh0akf7l.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ηλεκτρονικό-τσιγάρο-νέα-κριτικές-συμβουλές-στο-άτμισμα-.png

Comment: this is the code <h1 id="site-title">
           <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
          </h1>

Comment: What happens if you remove it?